# angularJS - Unable to load API Json response data into my HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

Here is the code that I am using:

```
angular.module('ngApp', [])
.factory('authInterceptor', authInterceptor)
.constant('API', 'http://myserver.com/app/api')
.controller('task', taskData)

function taskData($scope, $http, API) {
  $http.get( API + '/tasks' ).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.mainTask = data;
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>PCC ECAR App</title>

    <link href="../app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body ng-app="ngApp" ng-controller="task" class="">

    <div class="view1"> {{mainTask.Amount} </div>

    <!-- Third Party Scripts -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Main App Script -->
    <script src="../app/app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the console log from the API response:

[image]

What is happening is when you go to the page, the element `view1` will show `{{mainTask.Amount}}` for a half a second and then disappear leaving the element blank. I am obviously doing something wrong. Why cant I load the data into the HTML?

Comment: @FrankerZ. I did accept the answer. I'm not new to the site :) You just answered so fast that the site told me I had to wait another 10 minutes before I can accept a right answer. BTW the repeat option works awesome except in your response you forgot the last " } " after {{task.Amount}

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/Tasks` endpoint is returning an array of tasks. You would need to do:

```
$scope.mainTask = data.Tasks[0];
```

Or use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to loop through the tasks:

```
<div class="view1" ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks"> {{task.Amount}} </div>
```

Comment: that worked perfectly! and that will still work if there is 5 different objects being returned in the array.

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.mainTask.tasks` is an array that has your tasks data. You can loop through it in the view:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="task in mainTask.tasks">{{task.Amount}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It would be `mainTask.Tasks` as the api returns an object of arrays.